# prime powers in arithmetic progression

Tags: number-theory

I'm wondering about the asymptotic behavior of the function

$f_{n,m}(x):=|\{p\leq x: p$ prime, $p^n\equiv 1$ (mod $m$)$\}|$.

I'm aware of the asymptotic formula for the number of primes $\leq x$ occurring in a given arithmetic progression, but I can't find a reference for prime powers. In playing around with different values of $n,m$, there does seem to be some kind of convergence, but I can't discern the formula.

Comment: The main term will remain the same. In fact, the contributions from prime powers only bring an error of $O(\sqrt x)$.

Comment: Did you have an earlier version with $p^n<x$?

Comment: Yes! But that was a mistake.

Comment: @TravorLZH you misread the question: $n$ is fixed. Suppose $n = 2$ and $m$ is prime. Then $p^n \equiv 1 \bmod m$ is the same as $p \equiv \pm 1 \bmod m$, so the density is twice that of a single congruence class mod $m$ (when $m \geq 3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $n$ and $m$ are fixed: the condition $p^n\equiv1\pmod m$ restricts $p$ to the union of $k$ arithmetic progressions modulo $m$, where $k$ is the number of solutions to $x^n\equiv1\pmod m$ (which can be easily calculated, though the answer is hard to summarize). From there the prime number theorem for arithmetic progressions implies that the number of such primes is simply $k\cdot \frac{\pi(x)}{\phi(m)}$ asymptotically.

Comment: Hi Greg, I'm planning to submit for publication a short paper which builds off of the principle that you elucidated for me in your comment, and I thought I should acknowledge you for aiding my understanding and ultimately helping me formulate my result. Please let me know if you have any objections to this. The acknowledgment would read something like “I thank Greg Martin for helping me understand the density of primes satisfying certain congruence relations."

Comment: That sounds perfectly appropriate and I thank you for that acknowledgment ... I'm glad I was able to help :)